# How to use DispCallFunc to call IStream::SetSize(0) in plain C

Tags: c, winapi, com, ole

I have a `Stream` created from a `HGLOBAL` in WinAPI (in plain C, created with `CreateStreamOnHGlobal()`). I use it to save `GpImage`s to JPEG in memory.

I want to re-use the same memory stream to save multiple `GpImage`s. So, I need to reset the stream between each call to `GdipSaveImageToStream()`.

The documentation of IStream shows a method `::SetSize()`, but I'm in plain C.

I know that the solution is the WinAPI function `DispCallFunc` but I don't know how to use it and I can't find any good documentation about it.

Any help? Thanks :)

Comment: The .h file you #included (objidl.h) that provided the IStream declaration has both C++ and C prototype declarations.  The documentation is for C++ since that is by far the most common way to use COM interfaces.  If you use C then you have to use the C prototype function, Stream_SetSize(ptr, size) where ptr is the IStream* interface pointer.

Comment: @HansPassant that should be posted as an answer.

Comment: No idea why you are telling me this, anybody can post it as an answer.  You can to.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [IStream_Reset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for example, also even on plain C you can easy direct call interfaces methods, say IStream_Seek macro. DispCallFunc here absolute unrelated